# Closed formula for $a_n=a_{n-1} +2n +1$ where $a_1=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So how can I write the closed formula and walk to it from this sequence?
 $a_n=a_{n-1} + 2n +1$ where $a_1 = 1$

We were taught to start by subtracting 1 from any n on both sides of the equation but I'm stuck if I start:
 $a_n-a_{n-1} = 2(n-1) +1$ so if I evaluate the right side I'm left with $a_n-a_{n-1} = 2n-1$

Then we were taught to remove $a_{n-1}$ and to keep the recursion going:
$a_n-a_{n-1}= 2n-1$
$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}= 2n-1$
$a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}= 2n-1$
···
$a_3-a_2 = 2n-1$
$a_2-a_1 = 2n-1$
Then my notes say to "Add all these n−1 equations together".

So would that be:
$a_n-a_1=(2n-1)(n-1)$
evaluates to:
$a_n-a_1=(2n^2-3n+1)$
$a_n=a_1+2n^2-3n+1$
Which is not correct. Can someone help me through the process?

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\sum_{k=2}^n (2k-1)$? Because $a_{n}-a_1 = \sum_{k=2}^n (a_k-a_{k-1})$, so...

Comment: Figure out the first few values, and see if you can see a pattern... So: 1,6,13,22,33,...  see the pattern yet?

Comment: Notice first that if you ignore the non-homogeneous part, $a_n=a_{n-1}$ you get the characteristic equation $x-1=0$ and that constants are just constants times $1^n$ in disguise., search then for a solution of the form $bn^2+cn+d$

Comment: Please provide context, such as what you have tried.  See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) on why context is important for a good question.

Comment: I believe this looks like decent context. Perhaps the question can be reopened.

Comment: Your mistake is to believe that $$a_n-a_{n-1}= 2n-1$$ implies that $$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}= 2n-1$$ and $$a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}= 2n-1$$ and so on. My suggestion would be to think deeply about this step and to correct it. Sooo... you know that $$a_n-a_{n-1}= 2n-1$$ then, what would be $$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$$ equal to?

Comment: @did I'm thinking really hard it's been less than a week since I learned this.  

Wouldn't $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}= (2n+1)-(2n-1)$?

Comment: No, what you know is that $$a_{\color{red}{n}}-a_{\color{red}{n}-1}=2\color{red}{n}-1$$ for every $\color{red}{n}$, right? For example, $$a_{\color{red}{2}}-a_{\color{red}{2}-1}=2\cdot\color{red}{2}-1=3$$ Likewise, $$a_{\color{red}{43}}-a_{\color{red}{43}-1}=2\cdot\color{red}{43}-1=85$$ Now, what would be $$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\ ?$$

Comment: So would it be just subtracting one more from n on the right side? Would it equal 2n-2?

Comment: What? You think that $$a_{\color{red}{n}}-a_{\color{red}{n}-1}=2\color{red}{n}-1$$ then $$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=2n-2\ ?$$ Why?

Comment: @did no not really that's why I'm posting here. I'm just not seeing how all of this transformation works. Baby steps for me. What will knowing what $a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}$ end up telling me to help solve the original question? Please bare with me this is all new to me.

Comment: I do not know why you state that $a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}$ holds (it does not) but I do know that if you cannot deduce what $$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$$ is, assuming that, for every $n$, $$a_n-a_{n-1}=2n-1$$ **then this is what you should be asking about**. If you need a confirmation for this statement of mine, please observe that **every** answer posted below more or less takes it for granted that you can deduce it.

Answer (score 4):

$$a_N-a_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(2n+3) = N^2+2N-3 $$
hence $a_N = \color{red}{N^2+2N-2}=(N+1)^2-3$.

Comment: @jack-daurizio I just learned Sigma notation can you translate this on how you got to the solution so quickly?

Comment: @Kydd: the recurrence relation gives an explicit form for $a_{n+1}-a_n$, and that is a telescopic term. It follows that by summing $a_{n+1}-a_n$ over the suitable range you get a closed form expression for $a_N$, too.

Comment: As soon as you are able to sum $2n+1$ over the suitable range, of course.

Comment: Thans for the reply Jack but it's still over my head I'm not sure what you are saying. Haven't learned what "telescopic term" means. And what "as soon as" even refers to. Sorry total newbie here.

Comment: @Kydd: you live in the 21st century and Google is your friend - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Answer (score 1):

Write out the first couple terms and look for a pattern:
$$a_2=a_1+2(2)+2(1)-1$$
$$a_3=a_1+2(3)+2(2)+2(1)+0$$
$$a_4=a_1+2(4)+2(3)+2(2)+2(1)+1$$
and, without loss of generality,
$$a_n=a_1+2(1+2+3+...+n)+n-3$$
using the formula
$$1+2+3+...+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
we have
$$a_n=a_1+n(n+1)+n-3$$
$$a_n=1+n(n+1)+n-3$$
$$a_n=n(n+1)+n-2$$
$$a_n=n^2+2n-2$$

Comment: what does "without loss of generality" mean? How did you go from "using the formula" to $a_n=a_1+n(n+1)+n−3$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}a_n&=a_{n-1}+2n+1\\&=a_{n-2}+2n+1+2n-1\\&=a_{n-3}+2n+1+2n-1+2n-3\\&=\quad\vdots\\&=a_1+\sum_{k=2}^n(2k+1)\\&=n^2+2n-2\end{align}$$

---

Extra hint?

$1^2=1\\2^2=1+3\\3^2=1+3+5\\4^2=1+3+5+7\\\vdots$

Comment: why the -3 at the end of the 3rd line?

Comment: @Kydd Hint: $$a_{n-2}=a_{n-3}+2(n-2)+1=a_{n-3}+2n-3$$

Answer (score 0):

$n=1 \quad \rightarrow \quad a_1=1$

$n=2 \quad \rightarrow \quad a_2=a_1+2\cdot 2 +1=1+2\cdot2+1=2+2\cdot 2$

$n=3 \quad \rightarrow \quad a_3=a_2+2\cdot 3 +1=2+2\cdot 2+2\cdot 3 +1=3+2(2+3)$

$n=4 \quad \rightarrow \quad a_4=a_3+2 \cdot 4 +1=3+2(2+3)+\cdot 4 +1=4+2(2+3+4)$

suggest:
$$a_n=n+2(2+3+4+\cdots +n)$$

and, since 
$$(2+3+4+\cdots +n)=\frac{(2+n)}{2}(n-1)$$
because the sum of these consecutive numbers is the average of the first and last number multiplied by the number of numbers, we have:
$$  a_n= n+2\cdot \frac{(2+n)(n-1)}{2}=n+(2+n)(n-1)=n^2+2n-2$$

Prove that it works showing that $a_n-a_{n-1}=2n+1$

Comment: yes the  $a_n$−$a_n$−1=2n+1 is how we just learned to proceed! I'm just a day into this can you help me step into the logic? Just to confirm the n is always the index value/number NOT the value of the term of the index, that would be a, correct?

Comment: I'added something to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: Emilio-Novati can you take a look at how I was taught and perhaps suggest where my logic is off? We were also taught to transform the equation to get to: $(2+n)(n-1)\over1$ but the line where you wrote "suggest" wouldn't the 2 multiply to every item in the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

If the first difference $a_n-a_{n-1}$ is a first order polynomial, $2n+1$, then $a_n$ is a second order polynomial.

Write $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2\\
a_{n-1}&=c_0+c_1(n-1)+c_2(n-1)^2\\
&=c_0+c_1n-c_1+c_2n^2-2c_2n+1
\end{align}$$

compute the difference
$$\begin{align}
a_n-a_{n-1}&=c_1+2c_2n-1\\
&=2c_2n+c_1-1\\
&=2n+1\\
\end{align}$$

and identify coefficients of the same order
$$c_2=1$$
$$c_1=2$$

To find $c_0$, use

$$a_1=1=c_0+c_1(1)+c_2(1)^2=c_0+2+1$$
so

$$c_0=-2$$

Finally,

$$a_n=c_2n^2+c_1n+c_0=n^2+2n-2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n-a_1=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(a_k-a_{k-1}\right)=\sum_{k=2}^n(2k+1)=\frac{(2\cdot5+2(n-2))(n-1)}{2}=(n+3)(n-1).$$
Thus, $a_n=(n+3)(n-1)+1=n^2+2n-3+1=n^2+2n-2$.

Comment: we just learned sigma notation can you translate to English the thought process of how you go from left to to right?